# how to insert the element into the json array

Tags: javascript, json

I am having the json like this:

```
{
    json{
        "81":[
            {
            "name":"",
            "id":""
            },
            {
            "name":"",
            "id":""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am getting this json dynamically and i am storing this json in adlist. I want to insert the element into the array in the third position. i tried like this:

```
 var temp={"name":"","id":""};
 adlist.json[81].splice(2,0,temp);
```

But it is not adding the string correctly.

Comment: What error are you seeing? What does adlist look like after you spilce?

Comment: It is inserting the new element as one object

Comment: Your problem is rather about how to process arrays/objects in JavaScript. *How* you obtained the data (e.g. via JSON) is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
adlist.81.push({name: "Douglas Adams", id: "comedy"});
```

Comment: I couldn't see how the json is getting to adlist so I'm not sure of how it is structured. My point was to use `.push()`. Try `adlist.json.81.push({name: "Douglas Adams", id: "comedy"});`

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. You cannot access numeric properties with dot notation, you have to use bracket notation. That's the reason why you can only access array elements with `foo[0]` and not with `foo.0`. I.e. you have to use `adlist[81]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this too for better performance,

```
adlist.json["81"][adlist.json["81"].length]  ={name: "Douglas Adams", id: "comedy"};
```

Comment: @FelixKling Oops, I just wanted to implement amosmos answer in a effective/different way, Forgot to see that and realized the ill effects of copy pasting.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me :)

**Java Script Code:**

```
//your json data
var adlist = {json:{"81":[{"name":"first","id":"1"},{"name":"second","id":"2"}]}};

// your new json data
var temp={"name":"Third","id":"3"};

// insert your new json data in 3rd position
adlist.json["81"].push(temp);

// check with console
console.log(adlist);
```